# Write a query to find to the date between date A and date B

Tags: mysql

Please give me the idea using mysql query.

Comment: did you google for "MySQL between date query"?  First result shows the answer:  http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/between-date.php  Love the power of the google!  Use the power of the google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-05' AND '2010-02-05'
```

Also look up on `DATE_ADD` and `DATE_SUB` for basing on intervals:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html